# How to remove Write-Only on 'encrypted USB' from Laptop

Tags: access-control, usb-drive

My laptop has been policy enforced to write only on Encrypted USBs like Kingston DataTraveler 4000. Other USBs are read-only and not writable.

Are there any tweaks to have this removed.

I read one from [Is it possible to restrict USB keys to only certified ones, and block that key's access on other computers](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44604/is-it-possible-to-restrict-usb-keys-to-only-certified-ones-and-block-that-keys)

Comment: You mean when you are part of a domain which is managed with Active Directory? Generally no, until you leave the domain or the server manager changes the policy for you. Or you change the vendor and device id by modifying the firmware like it is mentioned in the linked question.

Comment: You say `My laptop`. Do you own the laptop or is this your company's computer? I'd be surprised if your computer has policies on it that you can't change.

Answer (score 2):

If your laptop is policy-enforced, then you must petition whoever has created your policy to change it. There is no known exploit to change this (other than getting admin access, which isn't really an exploit).

I would strongly recommend against trying to break out of your policy because these protections are usually put in place for a reason, even if that reason is silly. Besides, if there is a way for you to break the policy, malicious actors can also break the policy which is a serious security risk. Regardless, the question you have linked seems to be the best way to do things.